# Need explanation of the output. Need to understand the order in hooks & re renders work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not able to understand the order in which effects & re renders work upon calling set(state). I know that by default for every render effects are guaranteed to run. But in this case not able to apply that same principle to match the generated output.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  console.log("<===rendering===>");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running Effects")
    Promise.resolve(1)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("BEFORE SET flag", flag);
        setFlag(true);
        console.log("AFTER SET flag", flag);
        console.log("flag4 SET count", count);
        setCount(20);
        console.log("AFTER SET count", count);
      })
  }, [flag, count]);


  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output

1. <===rendering===>
2. Running Effects
3. BEFORE SET flag false
4. <===rendering===>
5. AFTER SET flag false
6. BEFORE SET count 0
7. Running Effects
8. <===rendering===>
9. AFTER SET count 0
10. BEFORE SET flag true
11. Running Effects
12. <===rendering===>
13. AFTER SET flag true
14. BEFORE SET count 0
15. AFTER SET count 0
16. BEFORE SET flag true
17. AFTER SET flag true
18. BEFORE SET count 20
19. AFTER SET count 20

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so you should upvote and/or accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what's happening:
the `Promise.resolve().then` is basically queuing the execution of the then block to after the effects phase, that's why in this case the `setState`s are triggering a new render immediately, then, before the next effects starts the execution of the then block continues.

I modified you code a bit to help understand better what console.log belongs to each render.

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-lake-heh9j

**first render starts**

```
#1 "<===rendering===>" false 0
```

**first render ends rendering**

**first render effects start**

```
#1 "Running Effects" false 0
```

**first render effects end**

**first render Promise.then block starts**

```
#1 "BEFORE SET flag" false 0
```

**first render setCount immediately calls next render because we are already done with the effect phase**
**second render starts**

```
#2 "<===rendering===>" true 0
```

**second render ends rendering**

**first render Promise.then block continues**

```
#1 "AFTER SET flag" false 0
#1 "BEFORE SET count" false 0
```

**first render setCount immediately calls third render because we are already done with the effect phase, but before the render react does the second render pending effects**

**second render effects start**

```
#2 "Running Effects" true 0
```

**second render effects end**

**third render starts**

```
#3 "<===rendering===>" true 20
```

**third render ends rendering**

**first render Promise.then block continues**

```
#1 "AFTER SET count" false 0
```

**first render Promise.then block ends => first render all done**

**second render Promise.then block starts**

```
#2 "BEFORE SET flag" true 0
```

**second render setCount immediately calls fourth render because we are already done with the effect phase, but before the render, react does the third render pending effects**

**third render effects start**

```
#3 "Running Effects" true 20
```

**third render effects end**

**fourth render starts**

```
#4 "<===rendering===>" true 20
```

**fourth render ends, does not have effects because count and flag did not change**

**second render Promise.then block continues**

```
#2 "AFTER SET flag" true 0
#2 "BEFORE SET count" true 0
#2 "AFTER SET count" true 0
```

**second render Promise.then block ends**

**third render Promise.then block starts**

```
#3 "BEFORE SET flag" true 20
#3 "AFTER SET flag" true 20
#3 "BEFORE SET count" true 20
#3 "AFTER SET count" true 20
```

**third render Promise.then block ends**

the following modified example may further help understanding what react does.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wozniak-syr0s

notice that when you click the set flag true button, no render is triggered because react does compare the new and previous states and **may** decide not to render.

Comment: In the Promise.then block of the second render `setFlag(true);` call initiates a fourth Render. i.e after **#2 "BEFORE SET flag" true 0**  So far so good. But then in the same then block for the same render shouldn't `setCount(20);` trigger another render? @tiago

Comment: At that point the differences I see for other setCount or setFlag is that the latest render in progress already has the same props **and** there are no pending effects. But I am not fully sure of the checks react is doing

Comment: Every render will have its own states, props, effects, handlers etc that always looks into the closure scope irrespective of even if the latest render may have something. Isn't it the way it is supposed to work? The first 4 renders follows this principle, How is it supposedly when **setCount(20)** comes it works differently? Isn't this inconsistent? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it's not a guarantee. react may do some optimizations. check the last sentence on the docs for useState https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate 
<< If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

Note that React **may** still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. >>

Comment: I updated my answer with another example to show how react sometimes bails out of rendering the component entirely if the states are identical

Comment: @anubhav-seal did this help?